# Element IDs are not being recognised and are not triggering function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create simple selection option for users when selecting a particular font style. If they click on a font `div`, the background of that `div` should change color.

The problem I'm having is that the first font `div` works perfectly in changing color - however the other font `div`s do not follow suit.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkLrd/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="fonts">
  <div id="font" class="minecraft-evenings">
      Hello
      <p>Minecraft Evenings</p>
  </div>
  <div id="font" class="minecrafter">
      Hello
      <p>Minecrafter 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="font" class="volter">
      Hello
      <p>Volter</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#font').click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
        $('#font').not(this).css("background-color", "#f1f1f1");
    });
});
```

Comment: For an `id` (`#`) selector, jQuery internally uses `document.getElementById`, which returns one element (or none)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jkLrd/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem:**
ID's are meant to be unique identifiers. You should be using classes if you want to identify multiple elements. For this reason, when you select by ID with `$("#font")`, jQuery (which uses native javascript's `getElementById`) will only return the first element it comes across that has that ID. This is because if the DOM is valid, it shouldn't find anymore instances of that ID and it would be a waste of processing to continue looking.

**A solution:**
Remove the `font` ID's from your `div`s and replace them with a class instead, like `class="font"`. Since you already have some classes identified, you can use multiple classes separated by spaces, like: `class="font minecrafter"`. After doing this, you will be able to select your elements with the `font` class using this selector: `$(".font")`

Comment: Technically the selector `[id="font"]` would work though :) I wouldn't suggest it, but I'm just saying

Comment: @Ian is right. `[id="font"]` would work because it's an attribute/property selector and although it will work for an id... it's not built specifically for id's (unique identifiers) and therefor will continue to look after finding a matching element. The reason Ian wouldn't suggest it is because it is not good practice to have multiple ids (to say the least).