# foreach textboxes with onchange js on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have an onchange event on every textboxes that I have. but my script only works for the first line of textboxes. can anyone help me?

```
            <?php
        foreach($get_order_details as $row_order_details):
        ?>

    <form method = "post">
        <tr>
            <td width="180px"><?php echo $row_order_details['name']; ?></td>
            <td width="180px"><?php echo $row_order_details['description']; ?></td>
            <td width="180px"><?php echo $row_order_details['qty']; ?></td>
            <td width="145px"><input type = "text"  name = "received_qty" id = "received_qty" class = "form-control" onchange = "myFunction1();"/></td>
            <td width = "145px"><input class = "form-control" type = "text" name = "cost" id = "cost" onchange = "myFunction();" /></td>
            <th width = "145px"><input class = "form-control" type = "text" name = "total_cost" id = "total_cost" disabled /></th>
            <td><button type = "submit" value = "" name = "received" class = "btn btn-primary">Receive</button></td>
        </tr>

    </form>

        <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
```

here's my javascript code.

and here's my script

```
            <script>
    function myFunction1()
    {
        var received_qty = document.getElementById('received_qty').value;
        var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;

        var total = received_qty * cost;    

        var cost = document.getElementById('total_cost').value = total;

    }
    function myFunction()
    {
        var received_qty = document.getElementById('received_qty').value;
        var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;

        var total = received_qty * cost;

        var cost = document.getElementById('total_cost').value = total;

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: is this your source ? this is terrible.... you really have to try to seperate html from php and js. to your problem... post your js please

Comment: Both of your functions do exactly the same thing. IDs have to be **unique**. If you really want to use jQuery, I suggest you read the tutorial first. That will explain everything you need to know about selecting the element and bind handlers to them: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/, https://learn.jquery.com/events/

Comment: yes sir, sorry I am new to js. the script only works on the first line of textboxes.

Comment: yes, because if the user change the qty received there I want it to automatically calculate also.

Comment: Then why don't you use the a single function instead of two doing the same thing? Anyways, check out the links in my previous comment and make yourself familiar with jQuery first. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18021584/218196 for an explanation of the duplicate ID problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fact that you wrote some about jquery ill provide you with this solution :)

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/D5skw/)**

some inputs

```
<input type="text" class="foo" id="i1" />
<input type="text" class="foo" id="i2" />
<input type="text" class="foo" id="i3" />
<input type="text" class="foo" id="i4" />
<input type="text" class="foo" id="i5" />
<input type="text" id="i6" />
<input type="text" id="i7" />
<input type="text" id="i8" />
<input type="text" id="i9" />
```

your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.foo').on('change', function(){
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks sir, but the textboxes there depends on how many information the foreach displays. if there are 5 info there should be 5lines of textboxes on it. but sadly with the same name it conflicts.

Comment: @user3113490 see my changes... you can use classes... if you build your form dynamicly  you can add class names to changeable fields and an change the `this` returns only the changed field. im sure you looking for this what i have posted :D in my pot is a fiddle... there you can see the behavior